# weblogic 12r3 on oel 7.1 cluster does not work

Tags: oracle, java-8, weblogic12c

I installed `Weblogic 12r3` on `OEL 7.1` but i am getting following error when trying to start cluster servers. But Standalone server starts without any issue.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.cluster.messaging.internal.GroupManagerImpl.mapServerNameToGroupNo(GroupManagerImpl.java:182)
    at weblogic.cluster.messaging.internal.GroupManagerImpl.mapServerNameToGroupNo(GroupManagerImpl.java:178)
    at weblogic.cluster.messaging.internal.GroupManagerImpl.findOrCreateGroupMember(GroupManagerImpl.java:233)
    at weblogic.cluster.messaging.internal.GroupManagerImpl.handleMessage(GroupManagerImpl.java:203)
    at weblogic.cluster.messaging.internal.ConnectionImpl$1.run(ConnectionImpl.java:139)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was managed server ports. We used 7006,7008 ports for managed servers but that ports creats error. We changed ports and everything works fine.